# Tag Warning Is Now Live for "Wireless"

Tags: discussion, tag-tips

Following up in the discussion about http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14237/tag-warnings-on-ask-ubuntu, we have added a tag warning for [wireless](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/wireless) on Ask Ubuntu!

[image: wireless tag warning]

We've only added one for now because we'd like wait until we have a better tracking system in place (which we don't have *right now*) before we add more.

Specifically, we'd like to be able to track the impact of those tag warnings in terms of:

- Causing users to not post their question at all
- Causing users to simply remove the offending tag

---

Here's why we selected [wireless](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/wireless) over the other suggestions:

- **EOL releases**: these warnings are about pushing questions away, we really want decent tracking in place before doing that.
- **Other OSes**: same as EOL releases.
- **Graphics**: [wireless](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/wireless) simply had more votes.

Comment: I really like this!

Comment: Let's hope it works.

Comment: Nice :) I might have a go at making a graphics info script to make things easier as well if you do want to implement that

Comment: Any plan to allow this for the other suggestions and for other tags in general? [We are currently discussing a tag misuse here on Meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14805/380067) and a suggestion to use a tag warning to fix the problem came up, but we're unaware of the current status of this feature. Can we have a little update on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we get an update on that tracking system? I'd really like some stats to see  if this helped.

Comment: Hey @Seth — I'm sorry I no longer work at stack, so you'll probably want to ping someone else there so they can look into it! ; )

Comment: Here you go, @Seth: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15205/tracking-on-tag-warnings/15207#15207 - tl;dr: it probably helped a bit, but not a panacea.

Comment: @NathanOsman - It would appear as though it is not helping :(