# Required info for wireless-tagged questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I propose that any questions tagged with `wireless` are **REQUIRED** to contain the output of:

```
lsusb | grep Wireless        #For USB adapters
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2    #For built-in adapters
```

As in, unless the system finds lines like, "Output of" in the question, you aren't allowed to post it.

Any takers?

Comment: And what about if your question is not about that? What about software recommendations to do with wireless?

Comment: How will you enforce this?

Comment: Question: "How can I connect to a wireless network from the command line?" That doesn't need any hardware information at all. There are various cases where a valid question can be asked without this info. I get where you're coming from, I just don't think it is something we could enforce automatically.

Comment: @muru How about having a popup box asking what you question is about?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda ^^^

Comment: @terdon maybe not completely automatically, but see ^^^

Comment: @AndroidDev that's already there, I think. Tag warnings are enabled on our site, last I heard, and wireless is one of the tags for which warnings appear

Comment: http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14270/158442

Comment: @muru - But it isn't working. We need "in your face" popups.

Comment: @AndroidDev that's probably feedback the devs should get

Comment: That's as in your face as it gets. Since you can't be 100% sure that a question needs the suggested information, you can't be more aggressive than a huge popup appearing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Disallowing [wireless](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/wireless) questions without stating "output of " [command list] is a bad idea because we will have a lot of questions which are for wireless things but do not need the output as identified in comments (for example, "How do I see detailed statistics in a graphical interface for all wireless networks near by me?" would not need that output but would still be tagged [wireless](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/wireless))

Best I would suggest is a nice big popup with a notice and a "Make sure you include information about your wireless adapter if the question pertains to malfunctioning or not working equipment", but not disallowing the entirety of the posting.