# Web-page did not allow posting a question about the vanishing WiFi icon

Tags: discussion

I tried to post a question about the WiFi icon and menu that vanished after going from Ubuntu MATE 17.10 to Ubuntu MATE 18.04.

The web page demanded that I include data on my hardware even though this is a software issue. I still have full internet connectivity. Just the icon and menu are missing.

I added the hardware info but the web page ignored it an demanded it again.
What good is Ask Ubuntu when it will not allow me to ask a question?

Comment: What web page are you talking of? `https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask` does not force you to include data on your hardware, as you can see in most of the questions here - including your own present one. You are required to select tags describing your question, but those are not necessarily on hardware.

Comment: You're wrong. A yellow pop-up appears to the right demanding hardware information and prevents submission.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tag Warning Is Now Live for "Wireless"](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14270/tag-warning-is-now-live-for-wireless)

Comment: The site is not smart enough to detect your hardware information (alas, we get many questions about wireless that lack hardware info and are therefore unanswerable, and we do need your hardware info for this) so the popup is not preventing submission. If you can't post your question, something else is stopping you.

Comment: **Do we really** close a user’s complaint **tagged [tag:discussion]** as a duplicate of the **unanswered feature announcement** here? o_O

Answer (score 2):

Don't fight the system, adapt to it.

- Your question is about the interface, wifi icon and the top panel.
- The system wants you to include hardware information when it thinks you are asking about a problem regarding wireless and it does that by checking for the tag "wireless". That is to prevent questions like "my wireless does not work. help me". Nothing to go on, a waste of time for all of us, including the person asking the question.

So the answer is pretty simple: do not mention wireless or use tags pointing to a problem with wireless. Mention the interface, gui in use: gdm3/unity, top panel, missing wi-fi icon. Things like that.

Comment: If [tag:wireless] is not about wireless in general, but rather hardware-related stuff, then the tag info should be corrected. Currently it reads *Questions about using Wireless connections in Ubuntu.* – a question about the WiFi menu is a perfect match.

Comment: The tag suggests it is related to the connection created when using wireless. So driver, network manager, settings for encryption. "Questions about using Wireless connections in Ubuntu. – a question about the WiFi menu is a perfect match. " The wifi icon has not really anything to do with the "Wireless connections" itself. It is a handy shortcut to wireless options. Nothing more.

Comment: @dessert are that icon and menu just for wireless connections? The equivalents in Unity or GNOME are for networking in general.

Answer (score 1):

Robert,

Wireless is very complex, so please [ask your question again on the main site](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) but add all the info as per [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/) and post a screenshot of what it looks like now and the best of the best will then review your question again and ensure you add the [mate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mate) tag as well.

Sorry about this...