# Regarding the influx of 16.04 questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

First off, I know that having a rush of questions for a late-development release is nothing new. It's just that *I'm* somewhat new and only just noticing this.

Recently, I've seen a *lot* of 16.04 questions. Our Help Center [explains questions on development releases are off-topic](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/871/when-are-questions-about-ubuntu1-appropriate), but no one reads the Help Center, especially not new users whose questions could be easily answered with 5 minutes of research.

I am wondering if anyone else thinks it would be a good idea to have some sort of banner, maybe somewhere near the top of the page, that appears somewhere within a month before the release of a new version of Ubuntu. This banner could appear to new users (less than 6 months maybe) that development releases are off-topic on Ask Ubuntu.

It certainly wouldn't stop all of the questions, but I'm sure many of them would go away. What does everyone think of a warning banner to new users? Maybe even a popup?

Comment: technically not all 16.04 questions are off-topic https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/871/when-are-questions-about-ubuntu1-appropriate. I think we should edit our off-topic reasons to clearly allow the ubuntu+1 questions we can answer, and clearly disallow those we can't. It rarely falls between a few numbers, even if the current policy would make you think it does.

Comment: The policy of closing questions on Ubuntu +1 (16.04 in this case) is less strict the closer to the release and "it depends" on if it is a support question or a bug. Support questions are better tolerated.

Comment: It couldn't really be a popup because most browsers automatically block popups and so do most privacy and security add-ons automatically so many people wouldn't see the popups even if you had them.

Comment: @Seth Well it wouldn't have to be static, saying all are off topic. It could be a reminder to read the Meta article about development releases.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen The banner could refer to the Meta post, as a reminder. Then it wouldn't have to be completely against all development questions.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda "popup" as in "modal".

Comment: There could be a red warning speech bubble when someone tries to add a 16.04 tag to their question, like for the deprecated "installation" tag.

Comment: @ByteCommander if that tag has that warning, it doesn't work. There's a new question with it  every day. Something more obvious might work better.

Comment: Stack Exchanges and pop ups do not belong together.

Answer (score 9):

Many questions (even though tagged with a version number) are not version specific and should be answered if possible.

I don't think the idea of a banner (or better yet a [support schedule](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)) is a bad one. However expecting people to both read and comprehend may be a stretch so I'm not convinced it's a solution to this problem.

I do however like the tag warnings as discussed [here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14237/tag-warnings-on-ask-ubuntu) and have in the past edited tags on EOL releases to indicate that fact.

Comment: What about something bright red, with bold title text?

Comment: Something like [this](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14237/tag-warnings-on-ask-ubuntu) (also [this](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14270/178596))? It should be do able for [tag:16.04], [tag:16.10] etc

Answer (score 6):

If you can remove all references to the version and still have an answerable question, that doesn't describe a buggy behavior, **just edit them**. Remove the tags and version from the question and allow the answers to sort themself out.

Comment: I probably should have made the question itself more clear. Maybe some sort of banner or modal that warns questions on development releases _may_ be off-topic, with a ink to a Meta post or something with more details.

Comment: A countdown, perhaps with a link as mentioned, might be an alternative with a more positive tone than an simpler "(almost) off topic" warning.