# Tracking on tag warnings

Tags: support, statistics, tag-tips

Is there a status update somewhere regarding tag warnings as discussed [here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14237/tag-warnings-on-ask-ubuntu) and the pilot implemented [here?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14270/tag-warning-is-now-live-for-wireless) I believe this to be a useful tool to both improve the quality of the site and increase the efficiency of moderators. It appears based on recent comments on the latter that [Thomas Orozco](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/40133/thomas-orozco)(who had been keeping us posted in regards to implementation) no longer has information regarding the status of this important and useful project. Clearly there is [interest](https://meta.askubuntu.com/search?q=tag+warnings) in this topic.

Comment: @kos added feature-request tag..

Comment: Stack Exchange employees look at metas in general, not just specific tags. This isn't a feature request..

Comment: @Seth thank you for clearing that up. Can you point me in the right direction as to usage and implementation of the just-in-time tag warning feature as discussed at http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14237/tag-warnings-on-ask-ubuntu ? Thank you!

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by "usage and implementation". The warnings have to be activated manually by an SE employee.

Comment: @Seth So it's not a feature request, do we need an activation-request tag?

Comment: you're asking for stats, that's not a feature request..

Comment: @Seth Clearly we agreed on that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, apparently Thomas put together a funnel for this before he left. I'm not 100% sure what his intention for using it was, so I'm just gonna post a screenshot of the current results:

[image]

Looks like we're discouraging *maybe* 12% of askers from posting in that tag. Which strikes me as... Reasonable. For comparison, here are the stats for every other tag warning currently in the system over this same time period:

[image]

Comment: To be noted that [tag:wireless] isn't really about discouraging people from posting, but discouraging people from posting without sufficient information (unlike the other two that were top of the wish-list). If 88% people went on to post, and many of them added the required information, I'd consider it a resounding success. And purely from personal information, many wireless questions in recent times came with the output of the wireless info script.

Comment: Thank you for digging into this! I believe the intent was to gather data to determine if it was a good idea to implement on other tags in the wishlist as posted at http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14237/tag-warnings-on-ask-ubuntu

Comment: I'm fine adding these, @Elder. I'll defer to the mod-team to sanity check 'em and let me know which ones are "ready" though. Particularly since one of those answers has like 50 tags in it.

Comment: I thank you and I'm sure we all appreciate it!