# Mint "tag warning" proposal

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

I propose that we create a "tag warning" for [mint](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mint), because it seems like we are getting a lot of OT questions about Mint.

Now you say, [this is a dupe](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/11508/would-a-off-topic-tag-warning-be-a-good-idea)!

Well yes, sorta, but nothing came out of it. Sooooo.... can we please look at this again?

Comment: Just a word of caution: this tag type was *intentionally not selected* when Tag Warnings were first being tested/implemented on Ask Ubuntu, because "these warnings are about pushing questions away, we really want decent tracking in place before doing that." (from Thomas Orozco, in [this other Meta thread](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14270/tag-warning-is-now-live-for-wireless)); for this to be reliably implemented, I think we need to evaluate whether or not we have such a 'decent tracking' in place for this to work.  (For this to work it has to hit all Non Ubuntu OS tags.)

Comment: @ThomasWard - It seems like they have "decent tracking" in place... http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/15207/518562

Comment: I meant tracking for "Other OSes", not tracking for the warnings that are being triggered.  Which is what I was trying to say about the reason they didn't chose "Other OSes" to begin with.  Just like tracking for EOL releases.

Comment: My main concern is that if we are implementing this for one tag that's not an Ubuntu OS, how far will we have to extend that?  I agree that this is a good idea, but I"m not sure how "wide spread" this would have to extend to really be captured.

Answer (score 2):

We are already doing very good at closing off-topic questions especially related to Mint. Mint-specific questions are being closed very quickly. So, these are not too much of a problem.

Also preventing a mint tag won't prevent a user to ask the question anyway. If we create one for mint, we need to create every other non-ubuntu distro. So, I'm not sure we really need this.

Comment: But what would the negatives be of implementing them?

Comment: Then we have to create a lot of tag-warnings for non-ubuntu distros